# undefined coming up in firefox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, firefox

my previous quesion was answered, but now the same thing that works in IE doesn't work like it should in Firefox.

my C# looks like this:

```
protected void OnRowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)  
{  
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)  
    {  
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", "sample(this)");  
        }  
}
```

my javascript looks like this:

```
function sample(rowIn) {  
    alert("D");  
    var gViewRowColumn = rowIn.cells[0];  
    var displayCell = gViewRowColumn.innerText;  
    alert(displayCell);  
}
```

The problem is that this works fine in IE but when I try it in Firefox, after alert D displays "D" the next alert just displays "undefined". I googled around and found some things relating to events but I could not understand nor correctly implement them. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such property as `innerText` in firefox, use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent)

Something like this should work for your needs.

```
var displayCell = gViewRowColumn.innerText || gViewRowColumn.textContent;
```

Comment: Thanks. that was wracking my brain. Is there a place I can go to see the list of stuff working for Firefox vs IE?
I hate trying to solve a problem for hours when its just my ignorance that was killing me.

Comment: @GetRichSlow1 Well this has some of the things you might encounter, hope it works out for you.. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html